# Access Controller from Job in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have a Rails Active Job job, but as part of that job I need to call a method from another Controller. I have tried like below but it fails.

```
Admin::Gallery::GalleryController.assign_albums_to_collections
```

Is this possible and how? If not then what is recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible<sup>*</sup>. Extract that logic from a controller into another class, so you can call it from both controller and job.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>unless `assign_albums_to_collections` is a class instance method on the controller</sup>